# Как обновить поля в модели Django?

Tags: django

Есть модель профиля:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('NewUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile', null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Хочу на странице добавить возможность обновлять имя в профиле, для этого:

views.py

```
class EditProfile(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = '/'
    model = Profile
```

urls.py

```
path('profile/', EditProfile.as_view(), name='edit_profile') (понимаю, что надо указать pk или slug, но можно без этого, просто использовав метод get_object() в классе представлении?)
```

forms.py

```
<div class="delivery__row-input">
    <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}" class="delivery__label">Дата рождения</label> 
    {{ form.first_name|add_class:"delivery__input" }}
</div>
```

Кто сможет объяснить и привести пример как мне исправить, чтобы работало?